# World of Warcraft API: Check if a bag slot is empty

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way, through the API, to look at a specific bag slot and tell if there is anything in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetContainerItemID
It returns `nil` if there is nothing in a bag slot